# How can I programmatically control the Microphone and Microphone Boost settings in Win7 from C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, com, volume

Windows 7 has some new audio settings which I haven't been able to control from my C# application.  Specifically, within the Input (microphone) properties, there is a Levels Tab containing Microphone and Microphone Boost sliders, and a Microphone mute toggle / checkbox.

I need to programatically ensure that the Microphone is not muted--but have not found the necessary APIs to either read or set the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very useful library built around windows mixer by Caster Tiu from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/AudioLib.aspx?msg=1323850

According to documentation on this page:

Specific controls like Fadder, Microphone Boost, bass, treble, etc. can be accessed via the MixerControl object using ValueAsSigned, ValueAsUnsigned and ValueAsBoolean properties, but they are not implemented as standard properties because they don't belong to all controls.

Comment: This project was built for XP.  It works only partially on Vista/Win7.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WalkTreeBackwardsFromPart sample that shows how to enumerate audio endpoints and print out their current volume, You can modify the code to [unmute the analog mixer via IDeviceTopology](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/9741bae1-c330-4802-9860-2fd202dba797/)

Windows should unmute the software volume at the beginning of a capture session, does your device have a hardware volume?

Answer (score 0):

The IAudioEndpointVolume interface might work for you. It has functions to get/set mute state and volume levels for a recording or playback device.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892(v=vs.85).aspx