# How to enable microphone boost programmatically?

Tags: c#, java, microphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically control the Microphone and Microphone Boost settings in Win7 from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440588/how-can-i-programmatically-control-the-microphone-and-microphone-boost-settings)

I want to write a little application which enables microphone boost. I've tried it with C# but I couldn't find any straightforward api to use. If you have done something like this before maybe you can suggest something. `Java` or `C#` it doesn't matter, I just need some ideas on how to increase the microphone boost (application will work on `Windows 7` and `XP`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't want you to mess with settings like that programmatically so there's no API for it.

The only thing you could do is actually opening the dialog and then sending mouse/keyboard events to do what you want. Of course that's not portable between OS versions.

Comment: how can I do that? I don't understand actually what you mean :/